Magento 2.4.7 Deprecated Functionality, Clearsale
After upgrading to m2.4.7-p1, we installed the newest version of Clearsale and see these errors:

Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property Clearsale\Integration\Model\Auth\Entity\CredentialsFactory::$ClientSecret is deprecated in /vendor/clearsale/integration/Model/Auth/Business/AuthBusinessObject.php
Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property Clearsale\Integration\Model\Auth\Entity\CredentialsFactory::$ClientID is deprecated in /vendor/clearsale/integration/Model/Auth/Business/AuthBusinessObject.php
Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property  Clearsale\Integration\Model\Auth\Entity\CredentialsFactory::$ApiKeyis deprecated in /vendor/clearsale/integration/Model/Auth/Business/AuthBusinessObject.php
Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property Clearsale\Integration\Model\Order\Entity\Payment::$CardType is deprecated in /vendor/clearsale/integration/Observer/ClearsaleObserver.php
We added to the file AuthBusinessObject.php:

protected $ApiKey;
protected $ClientID;
protected $ClientSecret;

Also, we tried to use AllowDynamicProperties (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/373345/55392), and we tried this script https://github.com/zagonico86/magento2-fix-dynamic-properties/, but nothing helped, we see the same errors. After each change, we wrote: PHP bin/magento s:d:c, PHP bin/magento c:f.  Note: We already wrote to the Clearsale, but have no answer. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you!

you just need to patch the code to add variables in /vendor/clearsale/integration/Model/Auth/Business/AuthBusinessObject.php and /vendor/clearsale/integration/Observer/ClearsaleObserver.php
If you are on cloud , use m2-hotfixes or if on prem install, refer How to apply the Magento 2 patches?
problem is -
class MyClass
{
        
    public function __construct(
        Data $helper // dynamic causing issue
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        
    }
    
}

and it needs to be -
class MyClass
{
    protected $helper; // you add variable before using in constructor to solve your problem
    
    public function __construct(
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        
    }
    
}


Thank you for your answer, as i wrote in the question, we added variables to those files https://imgur.com/KLl3ABj and https://imgur.com/dvZteZD

@Herecomes did that work or no? Also Clearsale\Integration\Model\Auth\Entity\Credentials & Clearsale\Integration\Model\Order\Entity\Payment
can you show constructor for this one and see variables ?

No, it didn't work.
`<?php
namespace Clearsale\Integration\Model\Auth\Entity;
class Credentials
{
public $ApiKey;
public $ClientID;
public $ClientSecret;
} <?php
namespace Clearsale\Integration\Model\Order\Entity;
class Payment
{
public $Date;
public $Type;
public $Gateway;
public $CardNumber;
public $CardHolderName;
public $Amount;
public $PaymentTypeID;
public $CardBin;
public $CardExpirationDate;
}`

What's the constructor for this file? I am free to help today.
Can you add these to the Credentials class?
public $ApiKey;
public $ClientID;
public $ClientSecret;

Thank you for helping me, https://github.com/herecomes/magento.stackexchange_375004 here you can find all files of this extension.

@Herecomes the version you shared doesn't throw any error when I compile me. Are you sure its throwing error ?
I am on 2.4.7 codebase php 8.2 in developer mode and used commands -
composer install && php bin/magento set:up && php bin/magento set:di:compile

what timezone are you in ? we can try to hop on call and see it your machine.

What version of magento you have and what version of php? We have m2.4.7-p1, PHP 8.2

Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.7-p1
PHP 8.2.23

This appears when keys are entered, and cron are working. You will see it in the logs. Extension send every 10min. orders to the clearsale.

Okay let me check
